# How to list files installed by a Haskell cabal package?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghc-pkg

Is there a way to list files installed by a [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/)  [cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/) package?
In other words: is there a way to list files associated with a Haskell package?

For example, in [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) based systems, including [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/), one can use `dpkg -l` to list all packages, and `dpkg -L package_name` to *list files associated with a given package*:

```
$ dpkg -L gzip
/.
/bin
/bin/gunzip
/bin/gzexe
/bin/gzip
/bin/uncompress
/bin/zcat
/bin/zcmp
/bin/zdiff
/bin/zegrep
/bin/zfgrep
/bin/zforce
/bin/zgrep
/bin/zless
/bin/zmore
/bin/znew
/usr
/usr/share
...
```

On [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/), the same is achieved by `pacman -Ql package_name`:

```
$ pacman -Ql gzip
gzip /usr/
gzip /usr/bin/
gzip /usr/bin/gunzip
gzip /usr/bin/gzexe
gzip /usr/bin/gzip
gzip /usr/bin/uncompress
gzip /usr/bin/zcat
gzip /usr/bin/zcmp
gzip /usr/bin/zdiff
gzip /usr/bin/zegrep
gzip /usr/bin/zfgrep
gzip /usr/bin/zforce
gzip /usr/bin/zgrep
gzip /usr/bin/zless
gzip /usr/bin/zmore
gzip /usr/bin/znew
gzip /usr/share/
...
```

Finally, using [Python's PIP](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/), one can use `pip show -f package_name` to show files associated with package `package_name`. [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/153843/how-do-i-list-the-files-associated-with-a-python-package-installed-using-pip-or)

Is there a way to do the above for packages installed through `cabal` using either `cabal` or `ghc-pkg`?  I know I can list packages using `ghc-pkg list` or `cabal list --installed`, but not how to list the files associated with specific packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ghc-pkg describe <pkgname>` to get a collection of directories under which the package's files have been installed. There are only a few things affected by a package installation that won't be mentioned by this:

1. The GHC package database itself is modified. `ghc-pkg list` will show you the locations of the two standard databases.
2. Executables installed by the package aren't known to GHC. You can use `cabal info <pkgname>` to get a list of executables.
3. Your build tool (i.e. cabal-install or stack) likely keeps a cache of package metadata and sources; these are not really "installed" in any meaningful sense -- deleting them won't break anything -- but they are bits of the filesystem modified by the installation process. For cabal-install this cache defaults to `~/.cabal/packages`; I don't know enough about stack to answer about that tool well.